# Display div and iframe horizontally

Tags: css, layout, html, iframe

Could you please give a html code for the following?

I need to display `div` and `iframe` horizontally fitting the whole page. But I need div to be fixed size (100px) and iframe fitting the remaining space.

[image: div+iframe]

Thanks

Comment: are you not using any javacsript or jquery??

Comment: @Uttara better try the CSS first before using jQuery, but if it's a quick job definitely a better way to go

Comment: @Aram Kocharyan thats ok, but your iframe is not fitting into the remaining space, rather its going beyond the window width.Hope you can see the scrollbar below

Comment: @Uttara ah, sorry didn't see that, fixed with auto width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gZNKk/1/

```
<html><head>
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #left {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            background: blue;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #right {
            width: auto; /* This is the default */
            float: none;
            margin-left: 100px;
            background: red;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #right-iframe {
            background: yellow;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right">
    <iframe id="right-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
</body></html>​
```

EDIT: Fixed the extra spacing on the right causing the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: I like @Dipaks's method for its simplicity if you're able to use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 3):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipaks2011/9ed4B/1/)

CSS

```
div{ border: 1px solid #f00; width: 100px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;}
iframe{ width: 100%; margin: 0 0 0 100px;}
```

HTML

```
<div>hi</div>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/"></iframe>
```

**EDIT:**

To avoid horizontal scrollbar define width in `%` to both the elements - [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipaks2011/9ed4B/6/)

Comment: but the iframe is going beyond the remaining space. I mean a horizontal scrollbar is added

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice that. Settings margin and padding doesn't work with 100% width because it adds to the width. What we'd like is 100% - 100px! :)

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
#content-wrapper {
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#content-left {
width: 49.5%;
min-height: 100%;
float: left;
border-right: solid 1px #A9D0D6;
}

#content-right {
width: 49.5%;
min-height: 100%;
float: right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='content-wrapper'>
    <div id='content-left'></div>
    <div id='content-right'><iframe src="http://www.google.com"></div>
</div>
```

Width you can adjust, whatever you required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/UUmsP/15/